Snap command line - what do two green asterisks mean?
Example:
~# snap info snapd
name:      snapd
summary:   Daemon and tooling that enable snap packages
publisher: Canonical**

What does "**" next to publisher name (Canonical in this case) mean?

I don't know why tou have two asterisks there, I have a green check mark there which indicates a verified account, see https://snapcraft.io/store?q=snapd and hover with your cusor over the green check mark. I get the asterisks when I pipe the output to a file.

Yeah it seems to be a matter of locale - I get a checkmark in my default (UTF-8) locale, but asterisks in a C locale (ex. using LC_MESSAGES=C snap info snapd)

Thank you for clarifications, this indeed seems to be an indicator of some form of platform trust. But I'm still curious why I couldn't find any official documentation for that.
